# how to access an element in a nested dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

how can I access `cost` in

```
coffee={"cappuccino":{"ingredients":{"water":250,"milk":100},"cost":45}}
```

Comment: read this https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Like this: ````coffee["cappuccino"]["cost"]````. Cheers.

Comment: Unrelated: you are missing a closing double-quote character after `ingredients`.

Answer (score 0):

`cappuccino_cost = coffee["cappuccino"]["cost"]`

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it backwards. If you already had `cappuccino`

```
cappuccino = {"ingredients":{"water":250,"milk":100},"cost":45}}
```

then how you would retrieve `"cost"`? You might already know that you can do it like this

```
cappuccino["cost"]
```

Now think about how you can get `cappuccino` from `coffee`.

```
coffee = {"cappuccino": {"ingredients": ... }}
```

Its the same idea as before

```
cappuccino = coffee["cappuccino"]
```

You can write it all out in separate lines if its clearer to you. Given that you have

```
coffee={"cappuccino":{"ingredients":{"water":250,"milk":100},"cost":45}}
```

You can write

```
cappuccino = coffee["cappuccino"]
cost = cappuccino["cost"]
```

Or you can be more concise and do it in one line. Take the last line, `cost = cappuccino["cost"]` and replace `cappuccino` with `coffee["cappuccino"]`.

```
cost = coffee["cappuccino"]["cost"]
```